# Columnwise operation on multiple mapped columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes namely df1 and df2. I want to perform operation on column "New_Amount_Dollar" from df2. Basically in df1 I have historical currency data and I want to perform datewise operation given Currency and Amount_Dollar from df2 to calculate the values for New_Amount_Dollar column in df2.

For 'Currency' == [AUD, BWP] We need to multiply the Amount_Dollar by respective currency value for respective date.

For other currencies We need to divide the Amount_Dollar by respective currency value for respective date.

e.g In df2 I have first currency as AUD for Date = '01-01-2019', so I want to calculate New_Amount_Dollar value such that

New_Amount_Dollar = Amount_Dollar*AUD value from df1 i.e New_Amount_Dollar = 19298*98 = 1891204

another example where in df2 I have third currency as COP for Date = '03-01-2019, so I want to calculate New_Amount_Dollar value such that

New_Amount_Dollar = Amount_Dollar/COP value from df1 i.e New_Amount_Dollar = 5000/0.043 = 116279.06

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', 
                 '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97],
        'BWP':[30,31,33,32,31],
        'CAD':[0.02,0.0192,0.0196,0.0196,0.0192],
        'BND':[0.99,0.952,0.970,0.980,0.970],
        'COP':[0.05,0.047,0.043,0.047,0.045]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'Currency':['AUD','AUD','COP','CAD','BND'],
        'Amount_Dollar':[19298, 19210, 5000, 200, 2300],
        'New_Amount_Dollar':[0,0,0,0,0]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
print (df2)
```

df1

```
         Date   AUD  BWP     CAD    BND    COP
0  01-01-2019  98.0   30  0.0200  0.990  0.050
1  02-01-2019  98.5   31  0.0192  0.952  0.047
2  03-01-2019  99.0   33  0.0196  0.970  0.043
3  04-01-2019  99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  0.047
4  05-01-2019  97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
```

df2

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298                  0
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210                  0
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000                  0
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200                  0
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300                  0
```

Expected result

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298            1891204
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210          1892185.0
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000          116279.06
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200           10204.08
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300            2371.13
```

Comment: How do you tell when to multiply or divide the value in df1 with d2? i.e. how to differentiate between multiplying with AUD and dividing with CAD? just if it's less than 1 divide?

Comment: No It could be any values not necessary less than 1.

Comment: If currency is AUD or BWP then Multiply by the currency value otherwise divide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `lookup` and `isin()`:

```
# this is to know where to multiply
# where to divide
s = df2['Currency'].isin(['AUD', 'BWP'])

# the values to multiply/divide
m = df1.set_index('Date').lookup(df2['Date'],df2['Currency'])

df2['New_Amount_Dollar'] = df2['Amount_Dollar'] * np.where(s, m, 1/m)
```

Output:

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298         1891204.00
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210         1892185.00
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000          116279.07
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200           10204.08
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300            2371.13
```

Comment: What if any currency is missing in df1 and I want to take the same "Amount_Dollar" in "New_Amount_Dollar".

Answer (score 1):

Try using `melt` and `merge`:

```
df_out = df2.merge(df1.melt('Date', var_name='Currency'), on= ['Date','Currency'])

df_out['New_Amount_Dollar'] = (df_out['Amount_Dollar'] * 
                               np.where(df_out['Currency'].isin(['AUD', 'BWP']),
                                        df_out['value'], 
                                        1/df_out['value']))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar  value
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298        1891204.000 98.000
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210        1892185.000 98.500
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000         116279.070  0.043
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200          10204.082  0.020
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300           2371.134  0.970
```